# Function not returning anything in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a web app's backend , where different posts are stored and their categories are also stored. Since each category has its own properties (like description , color etc. ) , I've created a new category schema and storing the category reference in the article.
Here's my post route:
[Code_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJrGs.png)
[Code_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lj0v1.png)

```
// CREATE ROUTE : adding New Article
app.post("/addnew", upload.single('image'), function(req,res){

//get data from form and add to news array 
var title = req.body.title;
var image = req.body.image
if (req.file){
    var imgURL = req.file.path;
}

var description = req.body.description;
var category = req.body.category;
var tag = req.body.tag;


// Handling the category entered by user
function checkCategory(name , color, totalArticles, desc){Category.find({name: category}, (err, foundCategory) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("found category in starting of checkCategory function : " , foundCategory)
        if (foundCategory[0]){
            console.log("Category" + foundCategory + "already exists...")
            return foundCategory
        } else {
            // var name = req.body.name
            // var color = req.body.color
            // var totalArticles = req.body.totalArticles
            // var desc  = req.body.desc
            var category = {name: name , color : color , totalArticles: totalArticles || 0 , desc : desc }
            Category.create(category, (err, newCategory) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log("New category Created : " , newCategory)
                    // category = newCategory
                    return newCategory
                }
                
            })
        }
    }
    })
}

console.log("??????????????? category returned", category)
var nyaArticle= {title: title, imgURL: imgURL, description: description};

// create a new Article and save to db 
Article.create(nyaArticle,function(err,newArticle){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // redirect back to main page
        console.log("new article created")
        console.log(newArticle)
        category = checkCategory(req.body.name, req.body.color, req.body.totalArticles, req.body.desc)
        console.log("checkCategory Returned :::::" , category)
        newArticle.category.push(category)
        newArticle.save() 
        res.redirect("/");
    }
})
```

The function checkCategory checks if the category already exists or else it will create a new one .
But according to these logs , my function is not returning the category created , however the category is successfully created in DB and also can be seen in [Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0zfR.png)

```
Articles App has started on port 3000
DB Connected...: cluster0-shard-00-00-ktzf1.mongodb.net
??????????????? category returned undefined
new article created
{
  category: [],
  hits: 0,
  tag: [],
  comments: [],
  _id: 60be0fe92a8b88a8fcea71dc,
  title: 'TESTING',
  description: 'TESTING',
  created: 2021-06-07T12:24:09.563Z,
  __v: 0
}
checkCategory Returned ::::: undefined
found category in starting of checkCategory function :  []
New category Created :  {
  totalArticles: 444,
  _id: 60be0fea2a8b88a8fcea71dd,
  name: 'TESTING',
  color: 'RED ALERT',
  desc: 'THiS TESTING',
  __v: 0
}
```

due to this null is getting stored in my category in
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIXGU.png)

Am I using the right approach or should I follow some other approach, any help is much welcomed.

The categorySchema looks like this :

`var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, color: String, totalArticles:  {    type:Number, default: 0 }, desc : String });`

ArticleSchema:

```
var newSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
imgURL: String,                                            //{type: String, default: "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x1080/?news"},
description: String,
// category: String,
category: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category"
    }
],
hits : {
    type: Number , 
    default : 0 
},
tag: [
    {type: String}
],
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
comments: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
]
```

});

Comment: Have you tried printing `req.body.category` which is used to query the collection. It seems like the problem exists here only.

Comment: there's not any key named category in req.body actually. You can see in function checkCategory , in the last else part , console.log("New category Created :" , newCategory)   logs the creation of new category , and in very next line  function is returning newCategory , which later on I am storing in category variable in Article.create and when I am logging that category variable it is logged undefined   ( checkCategory Returned ::::: undefined  ) . Why is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `var category` inside the [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) returned from your `checkCategory`, and that var is only available inside that callback.
Besides, you code have several other problems, like `Category.find({name: category})` which will never return anything. (it should be `{name:name}`).
In general, you'll be much better off using [`async\await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), (coupled with a [`try\catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch), if you like):

```
async function checkCategory(name, color, totalArticles, desc) {

    try {
        let category = await Category.findOne({ name });
        if (category) {
            console.log(`Category ${category.name} already exists...`);
            return category;
        }
        else {
            let newCategory = await Category.create({ name: name, color: color, totalArticles: totalArticles || 0, desc: desc });
            console.log("New category Created : ", newCategory);
            return newCategory;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

And in your router function:

```
app.post("/addnew", upload.single('image'), async function(req,res){

let {name, color, totalArticles, desc} = req.body;
let category = await checkCategory(name, color, totalArticles, desc);

let newArticle = await Article.create({ title: title, imgURL: imgURL, description: description, category: [category] });
res.redirect("/");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @ISAE . Can I increment the totalArticles variable whenever a new article is added to a category using a single query  i.e. while creating article ?

Comment: No. You'll have to do two separate queries, one for articles (creation \ deletion) and one for categories (increment \ decrement).

Comment: As general advice, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) about two-way-referencing in mongoDB